# AWS RDS PostgreSQL: what's the promised value for PostgreSQL replication lag?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a primary RDS instance with four replicas.

- Primary Database: Postgres, 4 vCPU, 16GB RAM, us-west-2a
- Replica1: Postgres, 4 vCPU, 16GB RAM, us-west-2a, 200G SSD (No
  traffic, just for testing)
- Replica2: Postgres, 4 vCPU, 16GB RAM, us-west-2b, 200G SSD (No
  traffic, just for testing)
- Replica3: Postgres, 2 vCPU, 8GB RAM, us-west-2b, 200G SSD (little
  traffic)
- Replica4: Postgres, 2 vCPU, 8GB RAM, us-west-2b, 200G SSD (little
  traffic)

The lag between primary and read replica exceeds 16 seconds without any heavy IOPS, sometimes 30 seconds.

I have spent a lot of effort on digging the root cause of lag.

Here is the CloudWatch report for a replica without any traffic.

[image]

### Assumption One: is it caused by IO credit?

Here is the report for IO credit, it's always 100% for the past six hours, I don't think it's caused by the IO issue.

[image]

Even I don't think it's caused by IO, I decide to upgrade the disk of the database from GP2 to IO1 with provisioned 3000 IOPS.

but it doesn't work, the lag is still there.

### Assumption Two: is it caused by the parameter hot standby?

There is no traffic in the replia! it has nothing to do with postgresql parameter `max_standby_streaming_delay` and `hot standby`

### Assumption Three: is it caused by Network IO?

the traffic is always less than 1M/s

### Assumption Four: Is it caused by long-running queries that triggered in my application?

I create two brand new m5.large PostgreSQL instance to verify this assumption, and use pgbench to benchmark.

- Primary: M5.large, with 3000 provisioned IOPS.
- Replica: M5.xlarge, with 1000 provisioned IOPS.

I'm surprised! the lag varies from 0 to 24 seconds.

[image]

You may ask why don't you post this problem to aws?

I have asked [this question in aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=967877#967877), but nobody answers me.

I feel cheated and would like to know the real value of replication lag from your experience.

### Questions

AWS Amazon Aurora provides an estimated value ([under 100ms](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html)) for the lag. Here is my benchmark report, the lag is under 25ms.

[image]

when it comes to AWS RDS PostgreSQL:

- Can anyone tell me what's the normal value of aws RDS PostgreSQL replication lag in the wild?
- What's the promised estimated value of the replication lag for AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Read replica limitations with PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html#USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.Limitations) in RDS documentation:

> If no user transactions are occurring on the source DB instance, a PostgreSQL read replica reports a replication lag of up to five minutes.

Can you check the replication lag, when having a script that writes to the database every a few milliseconds, as recommended [in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103806)?